# Collision detection with a Box Collider that has its isTrigger on Problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a box collider that should act like a view of the AI and i have a player that has a capsule collider and the game objects name is "Player". When i use the build it void that is OnCollisionEnter and exit (btw this didn't work even if i used the trigger versions of the voids) it just doesn't detect it. I tried checking if the player as a game Object collides with the vision collider with the "Equals()" command and that didn't work to. I have attached pictures and my whole AI script if someone knows how to fix this.

[image: zombie with vision collider]

[image: The box collider placed so it works with the script]

and the script

```cs
    using System;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.AI;

    namespace Demo.Scripts.Runtime
    {
        public class AI : MonoBehaviour
        {
            [Tab("Main")]
            [Header("Zombie States")]
            [SerializeField] public bool is_Chasing_Player;
            [SerializeField, Range(0f, 10f)] public float speed = 5f;

            [Tab("Navigation")]
            [Header("NavMesh Stuff")]
            [SerializeField] public NavMeshAgent agent;
            [SerializeField] public Collider vision_Collider;

            [Header("Player Location")]
            [SerializeField] public Transform player;

            [Tab("Animation")]
            [Header("Head Animator")]
            [SerializeField] public Animator animator;

            [Header("Animator Controllers")]
            [SerializeField] public RuntimeAnimatorController idle;
            [SerializeField] public RuntimeAnimatorController walk;
            [SerializeField] public RuntimeAnimatorController die;

            private int count = 0;

            private void Start()
            {
                animator.runtimeAnimatorController = idle;
                agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
                animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            }

            private void Update()
            {
                ZombieDie();
                if (player != null && is_Chasing_Player)
                {
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        animator.runtimeAnimatorController = walk;
                        count++;
                    }
                    agent.SetDestination(player.position);
                    agent.speed = speed;
                }
                if (!is_Chasing_Player && animator.runtimeAnimatorController != idle)
                {
                    animator.runtimeAnimatorController = idle;
                }
            }

            public void ZombieDie()
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
                {
                    animator.runtimeAnimatorController = die;
                    agent.speed = 0;
                    speed = 0;
                }
            }

            private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
            {
                if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Player entered vision collider");
                }
            }

        private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
            {
                if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Player exited vision collider");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I was trying to write a sentence in the console when the player collides with the vision collider.

Comment: you also dont need 2 colliders

Comment: do you have rigidbody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) instead of OnCollision when "isTrigger" is checked.

documentation says:

> One must have Collider.isTrigger enabled, and contain a Rigidbody

So add a Rigidbody to your agent and mark it "isKinematic".

When neither of them has a Rigidbody, the Physics Engine doesn't expect them to move and therefore collide. If you move the objects by script (navmesh agent) a kinematic rigidbody is what you want.

Comment: As i mentioned in the description. I tried the OnTriggerEnter and it still didn't work.

Comment: see the edit to my post

Comment: Both my player and the enemy have a rigid body that has its isKinematic On. I tried telling the void that vision_Collider = other to see if thats the problem but i guess no. And i changed it to OnTriggerenter and exit and that didn't help.

Comment: Depending on your hierarchy, collider.tag is different from collision.rigidbody.tag. Maybe log the objects name without checking the tag first, just to understand what's happening.

Comment: I don't know how i didnt think of that but still for some reason it logs "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" which is probably causing the problem. And btw i did it with "  Debug.Log(other.attachedRigidbody.tag);" cause there is no collider.rigidbody.tag.

Comment: I figured it out. For some reason when the player collides with the vision collider. Other.tag prints "Untagged" which even tough strange when i replace "Player" with "Untagged" it works. Thanks for the recommendation to print the tag.

Comment: try printing other.transform.name to see what is actually hit. I guess your prefab is tagged "Player" but not the objects that contains the collider?